# OpenCL / C++ host code running concurrently and memory maintenance

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to use OpenCL to accelerate certain segments of a pre-existing C++ simulation. Currently, I have selected a loop that runs for 1k-1M iterations on every simulation time-step.

To my current understanding, I have to manually write the data to the kernel using enqeueWriteBuffer to the kernel buffers before calling the kernel. I have to do this every time-step, before the kernel is called, so that the kernel operates on the correct data. Is it possible to make the writing of the data on the buffers to happen synchronously with the existing C++ code?

As it stands, before the kernel is requested, the existing C++ code executes another loop, which takes as long as my memory transfers take. This loop does not change or affect the data that I have to write to the kernel before calling it. Is it possible to get the memory transfer to occur synchronously for this period? I would prefer to have to host running the loop, while also writing the data to the buffers at the same time, saving precious simulation time.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to do an asynchronous write then run the kernel when the write has completed? Are you using the C++ wrapper API?

Comment: @TomFenech Yeah pretty much, but I want the writes to happen while the code is busy executing a C++ loop which has to execute. So instead of the kernel running like this 

1.C++ Loop
2. Memory Writes
3. Kernel
4. Memory Reads

I want it to run like this :

1. C++ Loop / Memory Writes
2. Loop Kernel
3. Memory Reads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a big problem here.

What you simply need is to **asynchronously** copy the data, while in parallel you perform another operation. That can simply be done with a non-blocking call to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()`. 
Additionally, you can even run the kernel in parallel and keep doing the C++ loop in CPU. There is no need to wait since the data of the kernel is independent from the other C++ loop data.

```
//Get the data for OpenCL ready
...

//Copy it asynchronously
clEnqueueWriteBufer(queue, buffer, CL_FALSE, size, ptr_to_data);
clFlush(); //Ensure it gets executed (not really needed)
//Run the kernel (asynchronously as well)
clENqueueNDRangeKernel(...);

//Do something else
... 
//Everything that is clEnqueueXXXX is run in the GPU, and does not take CPU cycles.

//Get the data back
clEnqueueReadBufer(...);

//Wait for the GPU to finish
clFinish(...); //Or, by making the read blocking
```

Comment: "you can even run the kernel in parallel and keep doing the C++ loop in CPU." Isn't clENqueueNDRangeKernel is blocking API?

Comment: @SagarKotecha Nope, all the "Enqueue" calls just queue something on a GPU queue, and gets executed "when the device can". So none of them are blocking. Unless the exception of the Read/Write calls that have an option to set them to be blocking to ensure data consistency after the call returns.

Comment: +1, the only thing that I'd add is that you might want to take a look at the C++ API especially if you're working on a C++ project already.

Comment: Yep this is great, and a very simple fix, I initiate the memory transfers before my C++ loop, and the only necessary change beyond shifting the code around, was setting the CL_TRUE to CL_FALSE on the write buffer. Made my simulation run around 6.8% faster compared to the blocking memory transfers

Comment: This code will not overlap copy and compute. The transfer will fully finish before the kernel executes. You need two command queues to do that (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, a wording correction: You're not writing data to the kernel, you're writing it to device, and the kernel uses it later.

To do what you want, you need two command queues, one for the data and the other for the kernel execution. Then use events to ensure the kernel doesn't run until the data transfer is done.

On AMD cards, this will get you what you want. On NVIDIA, your source memory will have to be allocated using clCreateBuffer with the CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag in order for the clEnqueueWriteBuffer to be asynchronous. See their sample: https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl#oclCopyComputeOverlap